# Assign a viewport width based on device resolution

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know that I can define the viewport size with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=330, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And I know that I can have the viewport adjusted to the device's with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

**Is there any way (without JavaScript) to detect the device width and assign a viewport:**

For example,

If the device-width is in the range (0-450px) to set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And if the device-width is in the range (451-900px) to set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I haven't been able to find any references online that detail this. I really appreciate any help or references.

Comment: No there is no way to do this without the use of javascript, but "width=device-width" is what you should be building for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what I was trying to do with JavaScript is achieved, yes, with a W3C standardized method.

Combined with media queries to change the styling of certain elements depending on resolution, simply define:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=width, user-scalable=no">
```

And the viewport will automatically assume the size of your page.